# XLSX Writer Format Row Borders for First n Columns

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I want to add bottom borders to the first 4 rows of a workbook, but only up to the 7th column. How can I restrict the range of columns to which this format will apply?
Here's what I tried so far:

```
import xlsxwriter
import numpy

format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_bottom(7)

for r in np.arange(4):
    worksheet.set_row(r,15,format)
```

This works great for formatting all columns for those rows, but I need to either delete all columns after the 7th column or find a way to restrict the range of columns to which the row format is applied.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you [cannot format a specified range of cells](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html#q-can-i-apply-a-format-to-a-range-of-cells-in-one-go), but, as a workaround, you can apply *conditional formatting* to a range based on a condition - you just need to set the condition to be always evaluated to true:

```
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_bottom(7)

worksheet.conditional_format('A1:G4', {'type': 'cell',
                                       'criteria': '!=',
                                       'value': 'None',
                                       'format': format})
```

The `A1:G4` should cover the "first 4 rows, first 7 columns only" range.

---

The complete working code I've used for testing the solution:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for row in range(11):
    for col in range(11):
        worksheet.write(row, col, row + col)

format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_bottom(7)

worksheet.conditional_format('A1:D5',
                             {'type': 'cell',
                              'criteria': '!=',
                              'value': 'None',
                              'format': format})

workbook.close()
```

Here is what I get in `hello.xlsx`:

[image]

Comment: So I just tried this and it didn't work for me. Do you have a sample where it worked? I'll try to assemble workable code in the meantime.

Comment: @DanceParty interesting, please see the sample code, hope it works for you. Also, make sure to have the latest `xlsxwriter` installed.

Comment: I just upgraded to 0.9.6 from 0.8.4 and I still do not see the bottom borders. It looks like it should work just fine. I used the code you provided.

Comment: @DanceParty probably not helpful, but I've posted what I have inside the generated file..ah, just noticed..the A1 cell does not have a bottom border, weird..

Comment: Thanks for posting the sample output. If it helps, I'm using OSX El Capitan (10.11.6), Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda 1.4.0 (Python 3.5.1).